# is vc++ is language or tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Is VC++(visual C++) a language or a tool? If it is not a tool, what is the difference between visual studio and VC++(visual C++)? Also, which compiler is used in visual studio?

Comment: Visual C++ is the language. MSVCC (Or Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler) is the tool.

Comment: To be more pedantic, however, Visual C++ is the IDE which edits the code - but considering that microsoft's flavor of C++ is radically different than the standard in some places, its fair to call it its own language at times.

Comment: I thought Visual C++ was the name of the IDE while the language used was C++.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, Isn't Visual C++ Microsoft's IDE? (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B))

Comment: @Anish it is, however when being discussed in a cross-platform context it rarely is referring to the IDE itself, rather, the subset of C++ that the compiler used by it supports.

Comment: I guess before ISO/IEC C++98, Visual C++ was its own language in a way.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: In what way is Microsoft's flavor of C++ radically different? Are you referring to C++/CLI or C++/CX?  Those are different languages that Visual C++ also supports.  But it also supports standard C++ (or near enough to it, no implementation that I know of is 100% compliant).

Comment: @James it still is its own language - it supports some C99 features, but not all, it doesn't fully confirm to C++03 specifications, and, it's prone to bugs that simply don't get fixed for a long time due to the nature of its releases.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm specifically talking about "standard" C++ here. When compared to other competing compilers (GCC, Clang, Intel's Compiler) it simply doesn't keep up with the standards out there, and many vendor specific hacks must be used because of it.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: It doesn't keep up in some places, no.  But it's also ahead in others, for example, its standard library is way more complete than libstdc++, even without having implemented initializer lists and variadic templates.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Good point, I forgot how they have ignored many of the ISO/IEC standards. But before standardisation was every C++ compiler its own language?

Comment: Comparison of C++11 features - http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, Why did you vote to close this question? The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) says questions which relate to _"software tools commonly used by programmers"_ are valid questions for the site.

Comment: @Anish we aren't a dictionary - when I voted to close the question, it was in a very bad state of disrepair. Unfortunately close votes cannot be reversed, and I was stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft is quite ambiguous in their language. For instance, [in one place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/60k1461a.aspx), they refer to "The powerful and flexible Visual C++ language and tools in Visual Studio". In [another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/zdbe067e.aspx), they refer to "the Visual C++ compiler tools" (without saying anything about a "Visual C++ language").

As far as I can tell, while Visual C++ (and/or Visual Studio, depending on your viewpoint) offers many Microsoft-specific libraries, they have made no changes to the C++ language itself. In my opinion, Visual C++ is a tool, not a language. The programming language supported by the tools is C++. (Actually, they support a couple of language variations such as C++/CLI and WinRT C++. But other IDEs and tools also support such variants. The language and the tools are not the same, despite Microsoft's persistent ambiguity in these matters.)

Also from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++):

> Microsoft Visual C++ (often abbreviated as MSVC or VC++) is a commercial (free version available), integrated development environment (IDE) product from Microsoft for the C, C++, and C++/CLI programming languages.

Comment: Yes, it's a tool, not a language. The language is C++. The Visual C++ environment supports targeting multiple languages, including C++. The difference in the documents you found depends on who wrote them. One clearly was generated by the marketing department. The technical writers will probably be more precise.

Comment: @CodyGray - Interesting hypothesis about the difference in authorship. My cynical view is that Microsoft intentionally uses confusing language to discourage developers from considering other tools. After all, if a competing IDE supports C++ but not "Visual C++" and I program in "the Visual C++ language", well, then that other IDE is clearly not for me. :)